# How do you use Dijkstra to find more routes?

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, dijkstra

I implemented the Dijkstra's algorithm to find the shortest path between 2 points. How do I modify it to find the N shortest routes? My idea was to add a small weight to the last node of the previously found path, but it doesn't always work correctly. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean the shortest path, the 2nd shortest path, ... the Nth shortest path?

Comment: Yes. Sorry for not being too exhaustive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are trying to solve is known as the **[K shortest path problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K_shortest_path_routing)**. The first algorithm to tackle the problem was proposed in 1971 by [Yen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yen%27s_algorithm), employing any shortest path algorithm to find the best path and then proceeding to find K − 1 deviations of the best path.

The running time complexity of the algorithm is `O(kn(m + n log n))`, which is pseudo-polynomial, where `m` represents the number of edges and `n` is the number of vertices.

An implementation of the algorithm in several programming languages can be found [here](https://code.google.com/archive/p/k-shortest-paths/).